# Difficulties on atributting a array to another

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm having a problem when i try to use a `char[20] array` and put it's "content" into another array of same size.

```
struct book{
   char author[20];
   char title[20];
};
book library [100];

void removebook(){
for (cont; cont<=quantidade; cont++){
    cont2=(cont+1);
 // HERE is where all goes downhill ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
    library[cont].author = library[cont2].author
}
```

the error i get is `[Error] invalid array assignment`

the intention is make a author name written on `library[4].author` overwrite `library[3].author`

like:

```
library[4].author=Mark;
library[3].author = library[4].author;
```

now whatever was on `library[3].author` was overwritten with `mark`

Comment: If you are not experienced with C++ you should use `std::string` instead of c style string (`char author[20];`) and `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of c style arrays (`book library [100];`). C style code can be very complex and error-prone. Therefore stl was introduced into C++. Modern C++ is much easier to use.

Comment: Perhaps if you were actually writing C++ code, and used proper C++ classes like `std::string`, instead of `char` arrays, this would work the way that you expect it to work. Otherwise you will need to review what your C++ book explains to you about arrays, and how to use them. Arrays themselves are not objects you can assign to each other. C++ does not work this way. You have to copy everything in an array, element by element, from one array to the other.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy an array with `operator=`. You can fix your problem using modern C++

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
// #include <list>
#include <string>
// #include <vector>

struct book{
   std::string author;
   std::string title;
};
std::array<book, 100> library; // or std::vector<book> library; 
                               // or std::list<book> library;

void removebook(std::size_t idx) {
    for (std::size_t cont = idx; cont < library.size() - 1; ++cont){
        std::size_t cont2 = cont + 1;
        library[cont] = library[cont2];
    }
}
```

Probably you can replace the body of `removebook` with a function from [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) like [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) or a method like [std::vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) or [std::list::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) depending on how you implement it, e.g. for `std::array<book, 100> library`

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

struct book{
   std::string author;
   std::string title;
};
std::array<book, 100> library;

void removebook(std::size_t idx) {
    std::copy(library.begin() + idx + 1, library.end(), library.begin() + idx);
    library.back() = book{};
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `std::array<char, 20>` as an alternative to `std::string`.   If someone is seeking to represent a string, there is normally a need to perform various actions that make sense on strings.    `std::array` does support assignment, but there are several operations that make sense on strings - which `std::string` supports and `std::array` does not.

Comment: @Peter I thought about the maximum length but I'm pretty sure you are right and I will remove it.

Answer (score 2):

When your attribute is defined as traditional C char array, your `=` operator between two traditional C char array will try to assign the right side first array address to the left side argument because `library[cont].author` is actually contains a constant char address in the memory.

The line:

```
library[cont].author = library[cont2].author;
```

Actually tries to take `library[cont2].author` value, which is constant char address, and assign it to `library[cont].author` which is also constant char address (which cause the failure). Even if it would work, it wouldn't done what you want it to.

The closest way to archive what it would done if it worked, is to define `author` as `char*`. Assume we allocated a memory for this attribute in every member of the `library`. The same line of code, would make all of the pointers to contains the same memory address, and now you can see how much troubles it would done.

The solution can be use `std::string` as mentioned in @ThomasSablik answer or as @Peter mentioned `std::array<char, 20>`.